# Android app runs on device but is incompatible in Playstore

Tags: android, device, incompatibility

I need your expertise here.

I have developed and published an Android app with targetSdk 28 and minSdk 21.

I use Visual Code and Ionic.

I tested it on a Samsung device with 5.1.1 and it worked fine.

I published the app and now the Playstore tells me it is incompatible.
It is also the case with a Samsung Tab A with 8.1

Why is this and how do I solve it?

Comment: Could you get target API 29 and try again?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would a higher target sdk help to resolve this incompatibility issue with a lower sdk?